Netplan IDs Scrambled After Timeshift Restore
This is my first question here as I generally figure things out through research and break-fix (flying that way since 1993).
I have a 24.04.1 LTS server doing many things, the most important of which is a KVM guest running pfSense. Today just before performing an install from a foreign repo, I performed a manual snapshot using Timeshift (like it). Moments after installing a package from this repo, I realized I'd made a mistake and decided to roll back to the manual snapshot. I understand this is a rookie way to do things, but I was feeling lazy, and had restored 'snapshots' successfully several times.
This time was different, as the network didn't come back as previously configured. The server has four NICs, two of which are bridged (vtap direct) to the pfSense guest. Another is for management, and the other is disabled.
For whatever reason, one of the previously bridged NICs was now the management interface. Unfortunately, that one is directly connected to the WAN, so the server was inaccessible via the LAN. The server is headless, so I connected a keyboard and display to figure out what was happening.
The effect of the issue was files in /etc/netplan had changed, and the static IP assigned to the former management NIC was now assigned to the NIC formerly bridged to the pfSense guest. I reconfigured everything and all is good, but don't understand what happened.
I'm using Network Manager, and the only thing I can figure is the system BIOS re-arranged the PCI resources, though that doesn't make complete sense to me (not sure how Network Manager decides what to do).
Does anyone have any experience that might help me narrow down the cause?
Thanks.
